# Functional Object in Polymorphism

Tags: c++, sorting, polymorphism, function-object

I want to implement Functional Object in Polymorphism as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Compare {
    virtual bool operator() (int, int) const = 0;
};
struct Less : public Compare {
    bool operator() (int i, int j)
        const {
        return (i < j);
    }
};
struct Greater : public Compare {
    bool operator() (int i, int j)
        const {
        return (i > j);
    }
};
void f(const Compare& c) {
    int arr[10] = { 4,2,6,7,1,3,5,9,8,0 };
    sort(arr, arr + 10, c);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
int main()
{
    f(Less());
    f(Greater());
}
```

But it has an error message "no instance of overloaded function "sort" matches the argument list"

I think that the abstract class cannot have an instance.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes the comparator parameter by-value; you can't pass an abstract class like `Compare` to it. You can pass `Less` or `Greater` directly to it.

You can make `f` template,

```
template <typename C>
void f(const C& c) {
    int arr[10] = { 4,2,6,7,1,3,5,9,8,0 };
    sort(arr, arr + 10, c);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

then pass `Less` or `Greater` to it like:

```
f(Less());
f(Greater());
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VjEQ24UzKp9zykmn)

Answer (score 3):

`std::sort` wants to copy the ordering function.

There is a standard class that "wraps" a reference and makes it copyable; `std::ref`.

```
#include <memory>

... and then ...

sort(arr, arr + 10, std::ref(c));
```